# mongo c libs not found on Mac with Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, macos, mongodb, driver

I built MongoDB C drivers from a tar distro on OSX (Mavericks).  Built ok and installed to /usr/local/lib along with libbson.  Made links to /usr/lib.

It built libbson-1.0.0.dylib, libbson-1.0.la, libmongoc-1.0.0.dylib, and libmongoc-1.0.la.
Not "*.a" files built tho, for whatever reason, by the makefile.

I added /usr/local/lib to my Eclipse project's lib dir params, and includes to /usr/local/include.

The includes were found during compile but linking failed because symbols from the libbson & libmongoc were not found.  I'm winding about the lack of "*.a" files--not sure if Eclipse knows what to do with dylib files.

How can I make Eclipse find the needed libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add "-llibbson-1.0.0 -llibbson-1.0 -llibmongoc-1.0" to the linker flags ?